I keep getting "INVALID_FLD_VALUE" during Inventory Assignment for Inventory Transfer in NETSUITE
Hopefully someone can help me with this error, i followed all the step to do Inventory Detail. This is the error i get, I'm trying to create a inventory detail for inventory transfer but it throws me an error. this is to transfer from a bin location to a non-bin location
{
   type: "error.SuiteScriptError",
   name: "INVALID_FLD_VALUE",
   message: "You have entered an Invalid Field Value 1449 for the following field: binnumber"
}

I have tried every solution i can find on the internet but i still get "INVALID_FLD_VALUE", below is one the solution I've used. I've tried using isDynamic = true, but i still got the same error. I've checked the binnumber and i can do manual Inventory Transfer and it seems that the binnumber is correct but every time i tried to run this script it always display "INVALID_FLD_VALUE". The binnumber has a select type is there something else i need to do?
var inventoryTransfer = RECORDMODULE.create({
            type: RECORDMODULE.Type.INVENTORY_TRANSFER,
            isDynamic: true,
            defaultValues: null
        });

        inventoryTransfer.setValue({
            fieldId: "location",
            value: fromlocation,
        });
        inventoryTransfer.setValue({
            fieldId: "transferlocation",
            value: tolocation,
        });
        inventoryTransfer.setValue({
            fieldId: "trandate",
            value: new Date(),
        });
        inventoryTransfer.setValue({
            fieldId: "memo",
            value: 'test IT'
        });
        inventoryTransfer.setValue({
            fieldId: "custbody6",
            value: presta_order_id
        });

        // Loop through each item and add it to the inventory transfer
        processItems.forEach(function (item, key) {
            log.debug('item', item);
            if (item.id) {

                inventoryTransfer.selectNewLine({
                    sublistId: "inventory",
                });
                inventoryTransfer.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "inventory",
                    fieldId: "item",
                    value: item.id
                });
                inventoryTransfer.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "inventory",
                    fieldId: "adjustqtyby",
                    value: item.quantity
                });
                inventoryTransfer.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: "inventory",
                    fieldId: "quantityonhand",
                    value: itemDetails.data[0].values.quantityonhand
                });
                // Create inventory detail (assignments)
                var inventoryDetail = RECORDMODULE.create({
                    type: RECORDMODULE.Type.INVENTORY_DETAIL,
                });
                var lineCount = inventoryDetail.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'inventoryassignment' });

                log.debug('line count', lineCount);

                inventoryDetail.insertLine({
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                    line: 0
                });

                inventoryDetail.setSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                    fieldId: 'binnumber',
                    value: binId, // Replace with actual bin internal ID
                    line: 0
                });

                inventoryDetail.setSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                    fieldId: 'quantityavailable',
                    value: itemDetails.data[0].values.quantityonhand, // Ensure this matches the transferred quantity
                    line: 0
                });
                inventoryDetail.setSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                    fieldId: 'quantity',
                    value: item.quantity, // Ensure this matches the transferred quantity
                    line: 0
                });

                log.debug('inventoryDetail',inventoryDetail);
                // // Commit the inventory assignment line
                inventoryDetail.save({
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'
                });
            }
        });
        // Commit the line for the item
        inventoryTransfer.commitLine({
            sublistId: 'inventory'
        });


You would not generally create the inventory detail subrecord.
var inventoryDetail = inventoryTransfer.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
    sublistId: 'inventory',
    fieldId: 'inventorydetail'
});

// You probably should be using dynamic calls on the inventoryDetail sub record

// If you are have a from bin number then you likely need a to bin number:
inventoryDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
  sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
  fieldId: 'binnumber',
  value: binId, // a valid bin internal id at the 'from' location
});

inventoryDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
  sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
  fieldId: 'tobinnumber',
  value: toBinId, // a valid bin internal id at the 'to' location
});


Another note is that I personally try to use non-dynamic mode for transfer order scripting. The code tends to be much cleaner.
